# Unable to update value in database using AND operator in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sql-update, sqlexception

I'm working on a *Java swing* application in which I'm trying to update *PostgreSQL* database when user make any changes.
 There are four fields in the tables, If I try to update one column at a time it's working fine but when I use `AND` then It display following error message to me

> Caught Exception:- org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying

Given below is code that I'm using to update table.

```
Connection con = DbConnection.getConnect();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "UPDATE webservice_config set product = ? AND product_cat = ? AND stock = ? where ID=?;";
PreparedStatement pstInsert = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstInsert.setString(1, product);
pstInsert.setString(2, productCat);
pstInsert.setString(3, stock);
pstInsert.setString(4, "1");
pstInsert.executeUpdate();
con.close();
```

Any Help

Comment: should be `"UPDATE webservice_config set product = ? , product_cat = ? , stock = ? where ID=?;";`

Comment: @vivek Id is here pstInsert.setString(4, "1");

Comment: @vivek Thanks, yes AND is creating problem here. Thanks for your help

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When perform `UPDATE` on a  table with more than one *column* you should use `,` to separate each column instead of `AND` operator,So your code should be like this:

```
 String sql = "UPDATE webservice_config set product = ?,product_cat = ?,stock = ? where ID=?;";
```

[PostgreSQL Documentation : SQL-UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

The **AND** operator displays a record if both the first condition **AND** the second condition are true